# xslt not showing results. xpath or ns wrong?

Tags: xslt, xpath, namespaces

i have the following xml and xslt to render it, but got no results. I checked again and again and see not path problem, and the xsl went through the compiler. so I am not sure if it's namespace problem or something else. many thx!

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bibdataset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/embase_com.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/common" 
xmlns:ait="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ait">
    <item>
        <bibrecord>
            <item-info>
                <itemidlist><ce:doi>10.1258/0268355042555000</ce:doi>
                </itemidlist>
            </item-info>
                <head>
                    <citation-title>
                        <titletext xml:lang="en" original="y">Effect of seasonal variations on the emergence of deep venous thrombosis of the lower extremity
                        </titletext>
                    </citation-title>
                    <abstracts>
                        <abstract xml:lang="en" original="y">
                            <ce:para>Objective: We aimed to determine the role of seasonal and meteorological variations in the incidence of lower extremity
                            </ce:para> 
                        </abstract>
                    </abstracts>
               </head>
         </bibrecord>
    </item>
</bibdataset>
```

XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/common" 
    xmlns:ait="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ait">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"
       media-type="application/xml" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <searchresult>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="/bibdataset/item/bibrecord" />
    </searchresult>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bibrecord">
    <document>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="head/citation-title/titletext" /></title>
      <snippet>
          <xsl:value-of select="head/abstracts/abstract/ce:para" />
      </snippet>
      <url>
        <xsl:variable name="doilink" select="item-info/itemidlist/ce:doi"/>
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="concat('http://dx.doi.org/', $doilink)" />
      </url>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed an issue with namespaces. In your XML, you have declared a default namespace meaning the root element, and all its descendants, and in this namespace.

```
<bibdataset .xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani"  ...
```

Now, in your XSLT, you have also declared this namespace, but without a prefix.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani"
```

This means it only applies to the elements you are outputting, so your **searchresult** element gets output in this namespace

```
<searchresult xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani"
```

However, it doesn't apply to the xpath expression in your XSLT, and so these are looking for elements in your input XML with no namespace.

In XSLT 2.0 the solution would be to simply declare an "xpath-default-namespace"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani" ...
```

In XSLT 1.0, you will have to declare the namespace with a prefix, and use this prefix in all the xpath expressions.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani" 
    xmlns:ani="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/common" 
    xmlns:ait="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ait"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ani">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"
       media-type="application/xml" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <searchresult>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="/ani:bibdataset/ani:item/ani:bibrecord" />
    </searchresult>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ani:bibrecord">
    <document>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="ani:head/ani:citation-title/ani:titletext" /></title>
      <snippet>
          <xsl:value-of select="ani:head/ani:abstracts/ani:abstract/ce:para" />
      </snippet>
      <url>
        <xsl:variable name="doilink" select="ani:item-info/ani:itemidlist/ce:doi"/>
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="concat('http://dx.doi.org/', $doilink)" />
      </url>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you can remove the line `xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani"` but that would mean your **searchresult** (and other) elements would be output with no namespace, so you would need to output it as `<ani:searchresult>` if you wanted it in the given namespace.